# Put two dataframe on the same sheet in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am doing some analysis on several different categories. I want to all the analysis to be on the same tab in a spreadsheet. So I have two dataframes for the information, but the columns are different and information different.

```
dataframe 1
      colA   colB   calC
row 1
row 2
row 3
dataframe 2
      colD   colE   calD
row 1
row 2
row 3
```

I want to export both of these dataframes on one excel sheet one after the other. The analysis are different lengths and I want dataframe 2 to be right below dataframe1 on a sheet.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetname,startrow=writer.sheets["Sheet1"].max_row, index = False,header= False)
writer.save()
```

// then do the same steps for any more number of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df2.columns = df1.columns
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

First make the columns of both the dataframes to be the same and then use `pd.concat` to append `df2` to the end of `df1`

You can create a new dataframe from this and export it to csv :

```py
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

If you want the header of the second dataframe also in your final csv file, create `df2` : `df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', names = df1.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra row to the second DataFrame with the values same as the column names. And then simply use `pd.concat()`

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df1.columns, df1])) 
#this will convert column names into rows
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df2.columns, df2])) 
#samewith other dataframe
#concat these dataframe and save as excel without index or columns
pd.concat((a,b)).to_excel('filename.xlsx',header=False,index=False)
```